# validate and match the zip code with bill/ship country in magento checkout

Tags: magento

I want to validate the zip code as per bill/ship country in magento checkout process.
entered bill/ship country should matches the entered zipcode.
If the entered zipcode and country did not match - customer should not be able to save the address and appropriate error message should be displayed.

Example:- customer entered zip code 12345 and selected country as US.
          Then it should display the message "Zip code do not match with selected country."

can anyone suggest me , how can i validate the zip as per country ?
Can i use the google API to validate the zip code ?
What portion of magento file i need to customize ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this functionality, first you need to map the zipcodes with countries or use any plugin for it. Then, define a model or table for it. Then, during checkout make an ajax call from zipcode field to your controller, call your model there and then check the pincode. Based on your comparison, return the result and display what you want to.